# R installation problems - Onedrive and Rattle

Tags: r, onedrive, rattle

I'm trying to install Rattle and am having problems installing RGtk2. I am using R version 4.1, so there may be a version compatibility issue. However, I noticed that RStudio is installing packages into OneDrive:

**Installing package into ‘C:/Users/tdwri/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’**

but I am using R in C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\

Question 1: how do I make sure packages are installed in C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2 instead of OneDrive?

Question 2: How do I install rattle when I am getting the error:
**package ‘RGtk2’ is not available for this version of R.**

Question 3:
If the solution to the second question involves downgrading the R version, how can I do that?

I apologize for asking 3 questions. I'm trying to get Rattle to work and these problems came up.

Answer (score 1):

### I found an answer to this at https://rattle.togaware.com/

LATEST NEWS: RGtk2 Retired From CRAN December 2021

### RGtk2 appears to have been retired from CRAN. To install it from the Microsoft CRAN snapshots:

This worked to get RGtk2 and install rattle
install.packages("https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2021-12-15/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.zip", repos=NULL)

Answer (score 0):

This worked- in addition don't forget to find file move it and resave it in the file you need it in.

**https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/carar/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Mac OS

From this link
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

- I Installed lower version of R
- I installed rattle library
- Upgraded my R to latest version and everything work fine

Comment: How to lower your R version?

Answer (score 0):

Rattle was archived on CRAN recently but after an update is being unarchived.

This may take a day or so.

In the meantime the following should work:

> install.packages("rattle", repos="https://rattle.togaware.com", type="source")

I just checked and it worked for me.

Also RGtk2 has been archived on CRAN though the author indicates it is remains functional.

Yes, please follow the instructions at https://rattle.togaware.com to install RGtk2 from MRAN instead.

> install.packages("https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2021-12-15/src/contrib/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.tar.gz", repos=NULL)